# how to validate the spring controller rest call responses, to prevent XSS attacks

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, xss

I am working in a project where security is high priority.
my project uses rest calls and i need to validate the response to prevent the xss attacks.
all the methods in spring controllers returns ResponseEntity.
we are using **angular 6 in the front end**.
When static code analysis is done by Fortify, then it is asking to validate response to avoid xss.

can you please suggest me which is the best way and how to do it , to prevent xss attacks in response **before response is given to the page**.

1) validating response at service level 
2) validating response at controller level

do i need to do it in each method ,can't i do it in a single place?

how to implement this? any sample code will be helpful

my sample code

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/path")

public class MyController{


@Autowired
private IService service;


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,path="/search",produces="application/json")

public ResponseEntity<?> find(@PathVariable("id") @NotNull final Long id){

SomeDTO dto = null;

dto = service.findResults(id);

return new ResponseEntity<>(dto,HttpStatus.OK);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need validate response, it should be performed while displaying. There are a few methods how to prevent xss on FE side. First of all, Angular do it for us from the box if you do not inject values as html, if you do not create html parts on the fe and do not inject it into DOM.

Comment: But when we run Fortify static code analyzer it is showing xss issues with the responses, so we are trying to fix them